# Why is Foo<'a, P<'b>> not the same as Foo2<'a>?

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

pub struct P<'a> {
    x: &'a str
}

pub struct Foo<'a, T> {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<'a + FnMut(&T)>>
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T>{
    pub fn foo(&mut self, payload: T) {
    }

}

pub struct Foo2<'a> {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<'a + FnMut(&P)>>
}

impl<'a> Foo2<'a>{
    pub fn foo(&mut self, payload: P) {
    }

}


struct Bar<'a, 'b> {
    x: Foo<'a, P<'b>>,
    y: Foo2<'a>,
    data: HashMap<String, String>
}


impl<'a, 'b> Bar<'a, 'b> {
    // fn test(&mut self) {
    //     // Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime.
    //     match self.data.get("foo") {
    //         Some(x) => {
    //             let p = P {x};
    //             self.x.foo(p);
    //         },
    //         None => {}
    //     }
    // }

    fn test2(&mut self) {
        match self.data.get("foo") {
            Some(x) => {
                let p = P {x};
                self.y.foo(p);
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bdea08a010852b5ed53b9a8b546bd50a&version=nightly&backtrace=0). I'm using rustc 1.19.0-nightly.

Why does `test2` work but `test` does not? How can I correctly make the generic struct `Foo`?

I do not think this example involves [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) and is not a duplicate.

Comment: Rust does not (yet) support having a field of a struct take a reference in a sibling field, therefore `x` or `z` cannot reference a value in `data`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  I modified the example, hope it doesn't involve the problem that "reference and value in the same struct".

Comment: Indeed, it is different now.

Answer (score 2):

What is `'a`, what is `'b`?

If we isolate the failing case (*note that I introduced a lifetime for `self` to make it easier*):

```
pub struct P<'a> {
    x: &'a str
}

pub struct Foo<'a, T> {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<'a + FnMut(&T)>>
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T>{
    pub fn foo(&mut self, payload: T) {
    }
}

struct Bar<'a, 'b> {
    x: Foo<'a, P<'b>>,
    data: HashMap<String, String>
}


impl<'a, 'b> Bar<'a, 'b> {
    fn test<'c>(&'c mut self) {
        // Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime.
        match self.data.get("foo") {
            Some(x) => {
                let p = P {x};
                self.x.foo(p);
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when you *instantiate* `Bar`, you *fix* what `'a` and `'b` is.

Specifically, this lifetime is NOT `'c`, which is totally unrelated.

The compiler sees:

- the argument to `self.x.foo` must have type `P<'b>`,
- it has type `P<'unknown>`, where `'unknown` is any lifetime *less* than `'c`,
- it has type `P<'unknown>`, so `'unknown` must be greater than `'b`,
- `'b` and `'c` are unrelated.

and has no idea what `'unknown` should be.

---

A potential solution is to avoid fixing `'b`:

```
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<'a + FnMut(&P)>>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn foo(&mut self, payload: P) {}
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    x: Foo<'a>,
    data: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

*Note: and at this point, `'a` seems superfluous as well.*

However this requires us fixing `T` as well, because when using a type parameter (as we had with `Foo<'a, T>`), then we need to fully specify the type and thus name the lifetime that `P` will contain.

Comment: I kinda guessed the potential solution as `Foo2` in my example. However, if I have multiple specific types of `T`, do I have to define like `Foo3, Foo4 ...`. Can I not reuse the code from `Foo`?

Comment: @colinfang: I am not exactly sure what you mean... note however that the whole difficulty comes from `P` having a reference inside, it may be worth exploring making that an owned value and bear the cost of having a copy (and possibly use `Rc` to lessen the cost of the copy).